# React Typescript: FunctionComponent with templated props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I have a component with templated props:

```
const MyComponent = <Value extends any>({ value }: MyComponentProps<Value>) => <div />;
```

Which I can use without explicitly specifying the type of Value (it is inferred):

```
<MyComponent value="1" />
<MyComponent value={1} />
```

I usually write my components this way:

```
const MyComponent: FunctionComponent<MyComponentProps> = ({ value }) => <div />;
```

But haven't found a way to template `MyComponent` and `MyComponentProps` with this syntax... Does anyone know how to do it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly is your goal?

Comment: I have a Tabs component which accepts `{ views: { key: Key }[], initialView?: Key }` so that `initialView` is always one of `views[].key`. First syntax works well, but I always use the second and would like to know if it is possible to use it in this case :)

Answer (score 1):

You can extend your ComponentProps like this:

```
interface MyComponentProps<T> {
   value: T
}

const MyComponent: FunctionComponent<MyComponentProps<string>> = ({ value }) => <div />;
```

Now value is whatever you pass in <>, for example string or any.

Comment: Yes, the problem is the generic is inferred in my first example, and I would like not to pass it to the interface

Comment: Can you elaborate on your code more? How do you want to use that component?

Comment: Edited to clarify a bit, hope this is clear but alas I don't know how everything is called in Typescript (yet), which limits my explanations

Comment: If you just want it to be any (as in your first example), just set value to any: interface MyComponentProps {
   value: any
}

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment you just want this:

```
interface MyComponentProps<V> {
    views: V;
    initialView: keyof V;
}

type KeyedFunctionComponent<T> = FunctionComponent<MyComponentProps<T>>;

const MyComponent: KeyedFunctionComponent<Views> = (views, initialViews) => <div />;
```

Then declare your function component using either an interface or "typeof views" as the generic argument. Which is good I think. But, what you really want is this combined with a generator, which will allow you to bind and template correctly:

```
// Declare some views constant:
const views = { home: "home", index: "index" };


// Declare a type for our bound views component
interface KeyedProps<V> {
    initialView?: keyof V;
}


// declare a type for our input function
interface KeyedWithViewsProps<V> extends KeyedProps<V> {
    views: V;
}


// This is the binding function itself
function createKeyedComponent<T>(views: T, toWrap: FunctionComponent<KeyedWithViewsProps<T>>): FunctionComponent<KeyedProps<T>> {
    return (props: KeyedProps<T>) => toWrap({views, initialView: props.initialView});
}


// Call the binder, and pass in the function we want to bind.
const MyComponent = createKeyedCompnonet(views, () => <div />);

// Now, using the component, only requires the optional initialView param, and it it type-checked to ensure it is a member of views
<MyComponent initialView="home" /> // works
<MyComponent initialView="other" /> // doesn't work
```

Comment: Edited to clarify a bit, hope this is clear but alas I don't know how everything is called in Typescript (yet), which limits my explanations

Comment: Take a look at my edit. I think it's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `value` to be any type:

```
type MyComponentProps = {
  value: any
};
```

or just one of explicit types (a.k.a. union type):

```
type MyComponentProps = {
  value: string | number
};

const MyComponent: FunctionComponent<MyComponentProps> = ({ value }) => <div />;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do

```
export type MyCompProps<ItemType> = {
    item: ItemType;
};

export const MyComp = <ItemType>(props: MyCompProps<ItemType>): React.ReactElement => {
    return <Text>item.toString</Text>;
}
```

Then I can just call

```
<MyComp item={myItem} />
```

And it figures it out.

Comment: Works flawlessly, thanks! Can we do that with the `const MyComp: VFC<Props>` notation?

Comment: Also, do you have a Typescript official documentation to refer for this notation?

Comment: This is the reference I use:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html